# Code coverage not processed in xcode 4.6 using coverstory even after generating .gcda and .gcno files

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, code-coverage, coverstory

I was trying to run code coverage in xcode 4.6 using coverstory. I followed these steps in the project's build settings:

1.Set "Generate Test Coverage Files" to "YES"

2.Set "Instrument Program Flow" to YES.

3.Build and run unit tests

After setting these flags to yes, I was able to generate .gcda and .gcno files in "i386" folder.

But while trying to open this folder with coverstory, the files are read but not processed.
It is showing a message "xargs: (null): No such file or directory" and also showing "failed to process files:".
I also tried coverage using gcovr and Icov, but it didn't work.

I followed these links http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-code-coverage/ and http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2012/06/unit-testing-load-of-image-resources/

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just reinstalled Xcode 4.6 and guess what it worked. Before this, I had faced different sort of problems during the execution of other programs also. I had a doubt regarding the problems with Xcode. Now after reinstalling it, code coverage can be easily executed using the cover story following the same steps. May be the .gcda and .gcno files were not generated properly.